# Is there a Byte Offset in FFmpeg for source Files?

Tags: c++, command-line, ffmpeg, offset

I am working on an C++ Application (running on Ubuntu) that opens FFmpeg for video conversion and reads the output through `popen()`. This works fine but now i need FFmpeg to start reading the source File at a specific Byte Offset. Is there any way to archive this? I already searched for a solution / command line parameter but couldn't find anything usefull. So is there any solution for this?

By the way: I already know there is a parameter for time offset but i need a byte offset.

Comment: Why do you need that? Is there some invalid data before the offset? Or should ffmpeg discard the samples before that offset?

Comment: I need that because i only got a byte position inside of the original file (instead of a time code) but need the same position for the encoded video to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) you might pipe your `ffmpeg` input file through `dd` and skip to a specific offset. Something like:

```
> dd if=myfile.mp2 skip=<myoffset-in-block-size> ibs=<block-size> | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 ...
```

or prepare another input file for `ffmpeg` without piping.

---

If you're working under [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), you can use [MSys 1.0](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys), that also supports `dd`.

Comment: This works! But i noticed its important to use ffmpeg command with -i pipe:0 otherwise ffmpeg doesnt take the output from dd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think FFmpeg support such special purpose feature.

However, it's easy to build your custom version of FFmpeg with a trivial avio input filter to skip bytes.

If you absolutely don't want to mess with FFmpeg, call FFmpeg to encode from pipe (stdin) and feed it with your file reader - but then you are limited to single input stream.

Comment: Well i don't want to mess with FFmpeg. I already thought of writing to the pipe but thats not working well with popen() as i would need to read and write simultaneously and this is quite tricky.